# Filtering on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i have a project, in there i want to add filter feature. i can make it but i have a bug in my script. when i create new data booking in same title/post the filter list increases and have same title/post. but in there i just want to make a list of them.

Image

[image: wrong]

its should be :

- Kost Alpha Charlie Delta Echo
- Kost Fanta Bintaro
- Home Test

here is my controller :

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $list = DB::table('data_kos')
        ->orderBy('id','asc')
        ->get();

        $limit = 10;
        $result = DB::table('data_kos')
        ->orderBy('id','asc');
        if(Request::get('q')) {
            $q = Request::input("q");
            $posts->where('title','like','%'.Request::get('q').'%');
            $posts->orwhere("sex","like","%".Request::get("q")."%");
            $posts->orwhere("price","like","%".Request::get("q")."%");
        }
        if(Request::get('title')) {
            $result = $result->where("title",Request::get("title"));
        }
        $data['list'] = $list;
        $data['posts'] = $result->paginate($limit);
        return view('kost', $data);
    }
```

and this is my view :

```
@foreach($list as $row)
        <li><a href='{{ url("booking?title=$row->title") }}'>{{ $row->title }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
```

what improvements do i have to make to the code to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *distinct*:

```
$list = DB::table('data_kos')
    ->distinct()
    ->select( 'title' )
    ->orderBy('id','asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: ahh, its work . but it doesnt work with if i use for join table.

Comment: ahh oke i found it i just need to add groupby in my controller when i use join stratement.

Comment: @AdamProjo great, glad I could help :) Please mark the question as resolved if this answer solved your problem.